# Run python script on my computer after Http Request

Tags: python, http, server

I have to run a Python script on my computer when i receive an http request and i have to send a response. How can i do it? I think my computer should run as a Server but i don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to provide us with the code you already have.

Comment: Have a look at the [python tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) - there is a whole section about web frameworks, which you are probably looking for. Other than that, your question is not really suitable for SO. Have a look at [ask].

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need to have an API. For that, you can implement a REST API with `FLASK` You can find a tutorial in the following link
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you could use flask, which would be simpler.

First you need to install flask and its dependencies:

```
pip install flask
```

Then you can do:

```
from import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = 5000)
```

Now you can visit localhost:5000 in your browser and see the response.

You could return JSON responses instead, depending upon your requirement. Flask can also render HTML templates if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need a web server for this purpose. [here](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/) you can learn about what a web server is and how to create a simple web server. 
following script from the provided link is the simplest code that can do what your expectation, you can put your script in the while loop:

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = '', 8888

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)
print 'Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT
while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print request

    http_response = """\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Hello, World!
"""
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    client_connection.close()
```

you can also use sophisticated frameworks like django if you want to do things more professionally.